# Laravel 5 API using json and Guzzle

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-5, guzzle

I'm quite new to Laravel 5 but I'm working on project involing 2 servers (S1 and S2). Each one is running a Laravel 5 REST WebService (API) WS1 and WS2.

The workflow is the following :

1. WS1 : just get a query like http://s1.ip/api/object/1 where 1 is the id of the object. It just "reroute" the query to WS2.
2. WS2 : get the same kind of query http://s2.ip/api/object/1 using a personnal access token from Laravel/Passport.
3. WS2 : Ask the local mysql DB to know if the object with id 1 is 'valid' or not.
4. WS2 : Create a response to the WS1 Query using json. Something like :
   {"id": "2", "valid": true}
5. WS1 : get the response from WS2 and from it create its own response to the initial GET query.

I test my REST API using Postman.

WS2 is work well when using Postman.

But when I try to query WS1, I never get the json from the response that is send from WS2.

Hope I clear.

Here are some of my source code:

**routes\api.php**

```
Route::get('/object/{obj_id?}', 'ObjectController@check')->where('obj_id', '[0-9]+');
```

**app\Http\Controllers\ObjectController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ObjectController extends Controller
{
    public function check($obj_id)
    {
        $token = 'my personnal access tokens from WS2 Laravel/Passport'
        $client = new Client();
        $body = $client->request('GET','http://S2.ip/api/object/' . $object_id, [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'bearer ' . $token, 
        ])->getBody();

    $contents = (string) $body;
    $data = json_decode($contents);
    dd($data); // to see what's inside $data
```

The dd($data) output the following : **null**

I have try many things but I never manager to get the json.
What am I doing wrong. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks

Edit:

Here is the S2 answer I got from PostMan or Rested:

S2 returns the following when using Postman:

```
Response - http://s2.ip/api/object/1

200 OK
Headers 

Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 08:38:31 GMT
Vary: Authorization
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.21
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.21
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Content-Length: 46
Response body 

{
    "id": "1",
    "authorized": false
}
```

Comment: What exactly does S2 return. Can you post a sample return from S2 here?

Comment: In S2, try to return the body only with something like `return response()->json($data, 200);`. So it gives you the content only. Then try to catch it from S1 in a variable, and transfert it as is like `return $received_data;`

Comment: I changed S2 to return `response()->json($data, 200);` but I still don't catch anything in S1 the `$data` variable is still null.

Comment: I hope you already found a solution, else, what you can do instead is just comment out `$contents = (string) $body;` and change the next line like this `$data = json_decode($body);`